# android getRelativeTimeSpanString() bug?

Tags: java, android, datetime

using the built in `getRelativeTimeSpanString()` method in android `DateUtil` I am unable to get the "minutes ago" "days ago" etc. time elapsed response that the documentation says that I should receive, instead I get a result that just displays the actual date in a way such as "may 12 2010", not sure if this is a bug or what but Ive tried both `getRelativeTimeSpanString (long time, long now, long minResolution)` and `getRelativeTimeSpanString (long startTime)`, both just return the actual date of the variable "long time"

here is my code

```
private void setJoineddate() {
    Date currentDate = new Date();
    long currentDateLong = currentDate.getTime();
    long oldDate = join_date.getTime();

    CharSequence relativeTime = DateUtils
                         .getRelativeTimeSpanString(oldDate, currentDateLong, 0);
    joindate.setText(relativeTime);

}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce (your code works for me).  Did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: @BilltheLizard i'm guessing the problem was that he was using 2 dates with a difference larger than 1 week (may 2010, dec 2011). `getRelativeTimeSpanString` only gives a "time-elapsed" type string for any time difference shorter than a week.

Answer (score 10):

Not a bug. `getRelativeTimeSpanString` will only give you a relative time string for up to one week in time difference. So if you use `DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(time2, now, 0L, DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_RELATIVE)` with the following values

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
long time2 = now - DateUtils.WEEK_IN_MILLIS;
```

you'll get `1 October` if today is `8 October`, but

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
long time2 = now - DateUtils.WEEK_IN_MILLIS + 1;
```

will give you `7 days ago`.

Comment: I'd say it still counts as a bug, this behavior is not documented.

Comment: @dpk I wouldn't call it a bug because of lack of documentation. The source code confirms this behaviour.

Comment: perhaps, however the code that is used to actually generate the "days ago" string is documented to support strings greater than 7 days, but it's locked away as a private method. That could be the bug instead. Or documentation fail. Either way, it's at least unclear what the intention was when writing either method, without consistent documentation.

Comment: But I think it's better to have something like "last week" or "2 weeks ago" against a resolution of `WEEK_IN_MILLIS`. For now, it seems like that `WEEK_IN_MILLIS` just ineffective for `minResolution`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this code

```
DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(oldDate, currentDateLong,
    0L, DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_ALL);
```

It will return `Just now`, `3 minutes ago` and so on. Read documentation and play with third parameter to modify strings returned by the function.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem. I was testing my app in an emulator, but then I decided to install the app on my nexus 7 just to see how it looked on a device and the relative time was fine.

It turns out that the date/time of the emulator was still set to the original date of the emulator's creation. I think this is because I launch from a snapshot, but for some reason the auto-update date/time wasn't working. I manually changed the time in the emulator and magically, the relative time was as expected.

Don't forget to change the timezone as well.

Answer (score 1):

Also had this Problem on my Device because the Device Clock was not set and showed 1. January 1970. After setting the correct Date it worked.